# I can't add drivers

Tags: drivers

So, I know how to add drivers, but for some reason it is not working at all.
I go to my object and hover over rotation on the Z axis, then I press ctrl+d and choose Single from target and the problem begins here I think. I use the eyedropper to choose my target, but I doesn't work. When I press on it the eyedropper just disappear like I added the target. But when I go to my graph editor (I choosen to show drivers no graphs) it is not there...
Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Leonardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eyedropper needs to hover a value, not an object; so in order to use it you have to open two properties panel, in one of them choose the target (in my example the sphere), pin it with the little pin icon, choose the source in the other panel. Anyway generally you will have to edit the added driver because often Blender doesn't guess exactly which value will drive which target value.

[image]